# What is the variance of an integral random variable?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, expected-value

In particular i have to find the variance of this random variable

$$U = \int_{-\infty}^{y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-T)^2} dx$$

where T is a ranadom variable distributed with a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

So i have to find the $Var(U)$. How can i find it?

Probably this is a cumulative function of a standard normal with some modification, but i don't know how i can approach it.

Comment: At https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482345 I have recently posted an analysis of precisely such an integral (for a Weibull distribution).  The trick is to evaluate the integral!

Comment: @whuber ah ok! so if i calculate the integral i have, with a sobsitution $u =x-T$ , i obtain that $U =\phi(y-T)$. But now, how can i calculate the variance of the cumulative function? because in the variance formula, i have to calculate $E[U^2]$, so how this expectation is?

Comment: Apply any of the techniques illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080.